# jquery function is not working in ajax success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function

when i trying to call jquery function in ajax success function but it is not call in the ajax function
here is my function
for example jquery function is below

```
function hello()
{
  alert ("hello");
}
```

And my ajax code is below

```
$("#loadmystatus").on('click','#removestatus',function(event){
        var statusid=$(this).attr('data-statusid');
        var flag="removestatus";
        var URL='changeuserstatus_ajax.php';
        var userid=$(this).attr('data-userid');            
        datastring='userid='+userid+'&statusid='+statusid+'&flag='+flag;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:URL,
            data:datastring,
            success:function(html){
              //dont call this function
               hello();
            }            
        });
    });
```

but this hello() function is not call in success function
please give me solution

Comment: any error in console??

Comment: @Vishal Patel did you try the following answer?

Comment: try to send object data instead of string.

Comment: try to do alert("hi ")

Answer (score 0):

Call function on ajax's `complete`:Like this..

```
 $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:URL,
            data:datastring,
            success:function(html){
              //dont call this function

            },
            complete:function(html){
              hello();
            }            
        });
```

OR use ajax's `.done`

```
 $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:URL,
            data:datastring,
            success:function(html){
              //dont call this function

            }     
        }).done(function(){
            hello();
        });
```

For more see here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: alert('success') inside success what is output?

Comment: congrats bro...best of luck ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see that ajax is successfully completing its request or not using error callback use below code

```
$("#loadmystatus").on('click','#removestatus',function(event){
        var statusid=$(this).attr('data-statusid');
        var flag="removestatus";
        var URL='changeuserstatus_ajax.php';
        var userid=$(this).attr('data-userid');            
        datastring='userid='+userid+'&statusid='+statusid+'&flag='+flag;
        $.ajax({
        url:URL,
        data: { query: encryptData('{"id":'+id+'}')},
        method:"post",
        data:datastring,
        success: function (data) {
            /* alert((data))/**/;
            hello();
        },
        error: function (){
            alert('Error occurred');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use jquery POST

```
$.post('URL here ' + '?' + datastring,{null}, function(data) {
  alert("First Success");
})
  .done(function(){
      alert("second success");
   })
  .fail(function(){
      alert("error");
   })
  .always(function(){
      alert("final finished ");
   });
```